# Security when passing req.body directly to mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Does it consider security problem when I pass req.body directly to the database (I use mongoose and nodejs)?

Let's say I have a person schema (name: string, age: number) and in req.body, someone tries to add an extra field to it. Do I need to extract only field that I need before passing it to db

```
const {name, age} = req.body
const person = new Person({name, age})
person.save()...
```

OR this is ok because mongoose already take care of that

```
 const person = new Person(req.body)
    person.save()...
```

Note: I am asking about extra fields, not about whether or not we should santinize the field that declared in schema

Comment: I mean.. you dont *need* to, per say... but yeah, you should always validate any input from the outside. I would def pluck out what you needed.

Comment: Extra fields are not the problem as they won't be processed in your schema but you should sanitize other fields.

Comment: Show us you `Person` constructor code and the save code.  There's no problem passing `req.body` to the `Person` constructor.  The question is what does that constructor do with the data you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a security problem in itself.
And that's not related with *Mongoose* either. That's pure *JavaScript*.

You are using destructuring assignment on the `req.body` params, so you are extracting exactly specified arguments.

```
const body = { name: 'bob', age: 12,  malicious_entry: "rm -rf" };

let {name, age} = body;
console.log(name, age, malicious_entry)  // ReferenceError: malicious_entry is not defined
```

And if you pass it to a constructor:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let {name, age, malicious_entry} = body;
let person = new Person(name, age, malicious_entry);
console.log(person)  // Person { name: 'bob', age: 12 }
```

I let you choose if you want to record an internet request directly in your database  without checking it, but clearly extra parameters are not the problem.